# What kind of files are valid Xcode behavior scripts?

Tags: xcode, applescript, file-format

I'm trying to set up an Applescript as a behavior in Xcode 4, but Xcode won't allow me to select my script. What kind of file is a valid script for Xcode? I've tried `.applescript`, `.scpt`, and `.txt`. I've also tried no extension at all.

What do I need to do?

Comment: I managed to select a file of kind "Script bundle" (file extension *.scptd)

Comment: After compiling the script to a script bundle, I get a bad file descriptor error when trying to run the behavior.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what I get for neglecting to read [the documentation on creating a new behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-alerts_preferences/CreatingaNewBehavior/CreatingaNewBehavior.html). (iOS developer login required.)

It turns out that Xcode can accept an executable file as a script. The solution was to run `chmod +x` on the script file and then Xcode allowed me to select it. It's funny, because I wasn't aware that Finder allowed filtering based on chmod permissions.

Comment: Thanks! In which folder should I place this file?

Answer (score 11):

While it appears you are looking specifically for AppleScript, **shell** files are valid for behavior scripts.

Create a new .sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh

#here is some code!
```

Make sure it is executable:

`chmod +x <my file name>.sh`

Assign it as the run script. That should be all you need to do.